# .htaccess redirecting all backlinks from non www. to a single homepage on www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to find out, how to make 301 redirections with .htaccess, tried lot of variations but nothing works as I need :( Can somebody help with this?

I have bought domain with backlings and would like to make there onepage microsite. I would like to link all backlinks to this homepage to get all the link juice. I found codes where it redirects it all, but the homepage didnt worked :( So I need to have that www. homepage working.

The microsite will be on https://www.website.com (with https:// and with www.) - simple onepage html microsite with text, imgs, and css.

So I need all links from https://website.com (with https:// and without www.) to redirect to  https://www.website.com. Not only links going to root domain https://website.com, but all others linking to all subsequent content on this non www version (for example like: https://website.com/anything/anything.anything).

I cant handle it myself, so I will appreciate any your help, thank you very much.

Most of the backlinks are pointing to homepage, but there are others linking to old pictures for example, which I cant redirect to new pictures, because they will not be present on the new onepage microsite. There are also links to some of old categories.

Last code I tried to use is following:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !https://www.webiste.com$  
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^000\.000\.000\.000 
RewriteRule $ https://www.website.com [R=302,L]
```

With this it is redirecting to [www.website.com](http://www.website.com) but the index is not working, it is still ending in To many redirections error, so as the same other tips of code was doing :(

Comment: "link all backlinks to this homepage to get all the link juice." - That probably won't give you the SEO benefit you are hoping for. A many-to-one redirect to the homepage will likely be seen as a soft-404 by Google (and other search engines). Can you please include the code you tried and exactly what happened and why it didn't work. Also, do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? What you describe is a relatively simple redirect, so there maybe something more fundamental that is in error here.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply and sorry for my late reply. I edited the main post, because here in comments it was to much characters. Thanks.